# Oops: IncompatibleClassChangeError - playframework

Tags: playframework

```
Model/My_Table_Name.java

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.db.jpa.*;



@Entity
@Table(name="My_Table_Name")
public class My_Table_Name extends Model{
    public int rid;
    public boolean siteEnabled;
    public String finalUrl;
    public String errorUrl;
    public boolean tokenRequired;

    public My_Table_Name(int rid,boolean siteEnabled, 
            String finalUrl, String errorUrl, boolean  tokenRequired)
    {
        this.rid = rid;
        this.errorUrl = errorUrl;
        this.finalUrl = finalUrl;

        this.siteEnabled = siteEnabled;
        this.tokenRequired = tokenRequired;
    }

}
```

Controller/application.java

```
@Before
    static void doSomething()
    {
        List<My_Table_Name> config = My_Table_Name.findAll();
        redirect(config.get(0).finalUrl);

    }
```

Error:

```
Oops: IncompatibleClassChangeError 

An unexpected error occured caused by exception IncompatibleClassChangeError:
 Implementing class
```

Stacktrace:

```
Oops: IncompatibleClassChangeError
An unexpected error occured caused by exception IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.onException(Invoker.java:244)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:286)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:129)
    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onApplicationStart(JPAPlugin.java:118)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:480)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:515)
    at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:618)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:198)
    ... 1 more
```

The above is my code and I am following the guide for the YABE tutorial with teh test for Post class, but figured I could use my own existing table in mysql db.

Comment: does the Play server start up without that model class and the @Before code? what version of Java are you using? (run 'java -version')

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this one out. Apparently when i ran the dependency for my project, it brought down older version of hibernate and in the classpaths there were 2 references to hibernate,

one in my lib folder

and one in the play\lib folder

i removed the hibernate *.jar from my app\lib folder and things are working